# ElasticSearch Downtime From Closing and Opening Index

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm managing an ElasticSearch cluster and I need to add an analyzer to one of my indices. The particular index I want to update is a bit more than 3TB. Will there be an excessive amount of downtime associated with closing and reopening this large of an index to add the analyzer? The documentation doesn't seem to say anything about the processing required to close and open an index.

I have done many rolling restarts and the shard recovery is pretty quick, but I'm guessing that closing and opening an index cannot be done one node at a time with a rolling restart.

Comment: Sometimes I have little delays when indices of tens of GB start the compression process (maybe exactly when they close/open). I imagine that the issues with a 3TB index will be significant. There is a suggested maximum size of 50GB; your index is 60x bigger...

Comment: may be you can check [Reload Search Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-reload-analyzers.html#indices-reload-analyzers) if it is search analyzer.

Comment: I second @SagarPatel, you didn't mention if it's an index time or search time analyzer. In the former case, you'll also have to update all your data in place in order for the new analyzer to correctly analyze the data. In the latter case, you don't need to close and reopen the index, just reloading the search analyzers is sufficient.

Comment: @Val (and Sagar) - I was going to try and get away with just using a search analyzer to avoid reindexing, but I think I might need to use it at index time as well. It is a character replacement to replace curly quotes with straight ones. It worked on my test cluster, but I didn't try search-only analyzer.

Comment: @dcolazin - I'm not going to say I know a lot about elastic, but I think index size doesn't matter; it's the shard size: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/size-your-shards.html. That being said my biggest shards are around 100GB, so I could reduce those to improve write speeds and recovery. However, the larger shard is better for reading and recovery on a rolling restart is acceptably fast.

Comment: 100GB shards is pretty big already... especially if the index itself is 3TB...

Comment: @Val - Right, so best practices would likely entail a reindex into a new index with a lower shard size limit and hopefully better distribution as there is a 1.5TB disk usage disparity between the biggest and smallest node. I'll have to delete from the old index as I go though, because disk space will get too tight if I don't.

Comment: Yes, but that's a different problem than the one you have now and can be tackled in a second time. Right now, the question is just: search- vs index-time analyzer. And the answer is simple: The former has no downtime while the latter does and requires you to update your index if you want to analyzer to kick in and properly analyze your existing data. Depending on your analyzer, quotes (curly or otherwise) are probably removed anyway at indexing time

Comment: @Val - In the example for reloading the analyzer it includes a PUT request to create the new analyzer. I can't send that PUT to create the analyzer without closing the index.

Comment: The PUT request is to create a new index... You only need to `PUT /xyz/_settings` to store the new analyzer and then call `POST /xyz/_reload_search_analyzers` on your index

Comment: @Val - PUT /xyz/_settings returns "Can't update non dynamic settings for open indices".

Comment: Yeah, it's true that the `_reload_search_analyzers` endpoint is mainly for telling the nodes to pick up the latest synonyms from a synonyms file... it might not apply to your specific case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the official document of [open index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-open-close.html#open-index-api-desc)

> When opening or closing an index, the master is responsible for
> restarting the index shards to reflect the new state of the index. The
> shards will then go through the normal recovery process. The data of
> opened/closed indices is automatically replicated by the cluster to
> ensure that enough shard copies are safely kept around at all times.

This clearly explains that its not a cheap operation, and if you have many shards in your cluster and your cluster state is big, updating that to all the nodes can cause significant overhead.

Apart from this, opening and closing an index also allocates the shards, again explained in the same document section of [wait for active shards](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-open-close.html#open-index-api-wait-for-active-shards)

> Because opening or closing an index allocates its shards, the
> wait_for_active_shards setting on index creation applies to the _open
> and _close index actions as well.

**And this one is a major overhead as it involves moving the data ie shards in the cluster and your is a very index, so it can cause huge data movement is your cluster.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: This particular index has 28 shards that are 110 - 130GB spread across 5 nodes. Recovery on a rolling restart is pretty quick, but I'm guessing you can't close and open an index one node at a time.

Comment: @Ian, yes you can't open and close index per node basis when its shards are spreaded across multiple nodes..